# detect successive repetitions in R

Tags: r

in R, I would like to find out whether there are successive repetitions in my data.

```
A <- c(1,2,3,3,4)

B <- c(1,2,3,4,3)
```

For A, I want to get TRUE, since there are two 3s directly one after the other.

For B, I want to get FALSE because the 3s are separated by the 4.

Thanks community!
pointingeye

Comment: Look at `rle` for the answer.

Comment: Or you could try `any(c(FALSE,A[-1]==A[-length(A)]))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`rle`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) for this:

```
> rle(A)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 1 1 2 1
  values : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
> any(rle(A)$lengths > 1)
[1] TRUE
> any(rle(B)$lengths > 1)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [`rle`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html):

```
any(rle(A)$lengths > 1)
#[1] TRUE
any(rle(B)$lengths > 1)
#[1] FALSE
```

Alternative solution ([`diff`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html)):

```
any(diff(A)==0)
#[1] TRUE
any(diff(B)==0)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: No, this is kind of a tie.  So, no need to remove.  You may also suggest other options like the one I posted as comment

Answer (score 2):

```
0 %in% diff(A) - TRUE
0 %in% diff(B) - FALSE
```

Only in case of (at least) two successive identical numbers difference can be equal to 0.